# How to get IMEI number in Blackberry 10 device using webworks?

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10, imei

I am working on Blackberry 10 App using webworks and I want to get the device IMEI number using webworks. I did not find any solution to get IMEI number on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript include this code

```
function functionName()
        {
            var transportList = blackberry.identity;
            IMEI_No = transportList.IMEI;
        }
```

and in config file include

```
<feature id="blackberry.identity" />
```

This will return the Imei number.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Identity API - https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.identity.html

It will return the IMEI and the UUID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have already tried this but This gives an error "blackberry is not defined". Can you please tell me how to do it.

Thanks in advance